# Dot Product proof that results in the smallest set

Tags: linear-algebra, products, integers

I am looking for a formal proof of the following, because I strongly believe there exist a theorem on it already that I want to cite, but if not the proof will suffice.

Given a list $A$ and list $B$ of $n$ positive integers. If I order $A$ in a increasing order and order $B$ in decreasing order, then if I take the dot product of $A$ and $B$ then the result is of minimum value.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the [Rearrangement Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) and you can find details and a proof at the link provided above.